# Can I draw linear interpolation graph for set of x and y values using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, linear-interpolation

Can I draw linear interpolation graph for set of x and y values using numpy ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x =[700,701,702,702]
y =[46,48,45,45]
​
​
x_new= [701]
​
y_new = np.interp(x_new, x, y)
print(y_new)
[48.]
plt.plot(x, y, "og-", x_new, y_new, "or");
```

How can I print the function used in graph?

Comment: Your code seems fine, what is the issue?

Comment: I gave x_new value by approximation. Can I find the value of x_new? I need to see the function used.Dont know how to print it

Comment: What do you mean by "print the function used"? You mean show the graph? Use `plt.show()` at the end, or `plt.savefig(/path/to/file)` to save it to a file.

Comment: i cant see the function they have used in graph?

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the function used in the graph as the equation of the line? If so, to get the equation of the line:

```
from numpy import ones,vstack
from numpy.linalg import lstsq

x =[700,701,702,702]
y =[46,48,45,45]
A = vstack([x_coords,ones(len(x_coords))]).T
m, c = lstsq(A, y_coords)[0]
print("Line Solution is y = {m}x + {c}".format(m=m,c=c))
```